# Error during Label Encoding Sci-kit Library

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to encode my dataframe which is in the form strings but i am receiving this error :

> error :
>
> *'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'NoneType'",
> 'occurred at index ProductFabric'*

CODE:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing 
df1=df1.apply(preprocessing.LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
```

Answer (score 1):

here is an example from sklearn documentation hope this will help you
however in your case, you are taking df which might be a dataFrame with multiple column or there might be null values

```
    from sklearn import preprocessing
    df = [1, 1, 2, 6]
    le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df) 
    print(le)
```